# Why is 'weeks' from specific date not calculated?

Tags: r, date

I have a sample `q` below that contains three dates of `dd/mm/yy` in `q$test`

```
    test
1 210376
2 141292
3 280280
```

I want to create a new covariate `q$new` that calculates the date difference from `q$test` to today.

I tried

```
q$new <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(q$test,format='%d/%m/%y'), as.Date(Sys.Date()), unit="weeks"))
```

But I receive an error message

> Error in q$new <- as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(q$test, format =
>   "%d/%m/%y"),  :    object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Do you have any idea whats wrong? Or have another solution?

```
q <- structure(list(test = c(210376L, 141292L, 280280L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), as.Date(as.character(q$test), "%d%m%y"), units = "weeks"))
#[1] 2257.286 1384.143 2051.714
```

Few pointers -

1) `Sys.Date` is already of class "Date" so no need for `as.Date` there

2) `as.Date` was expecting a character string as input hence wrapped `q$test` in `as.character`

3) `format` in `as.Date` is used to represent the format we have as input and not the output we want. So in your case you used the format `"%d/%m/%y"` whereas the format you had was `%d%m%y`.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that OP also used the wrong format. It should be `"%d%m%y"` as you used, instead of separating them by `/`.